# Validations for dialogs

Tags: validation, dialog, warnings

We developed a behavior, that presents warnings in the lower part of the dialog, in case that exists, after hitting the dialog button. The user can move forward with the warning.
However, in some case the warning is known when the dialog is opened, e.g. the user gets a warning while trying to move entities with status x. In the current behavior, the user will open the dialog, select the entities and while hitting the button, the warning will be presented. 
Another option for the user is to first select the entities from a grid and then open the dialog, meaning that the warning, if exist, is already known. What is the best practice in this case? opening the dialog with the warnings already presented/ only showing the warnings after hitting the dialog button?

The first picture is the dialog, the second is what happens after clicking on 'perform operation' when there are warnings. 
My question is if this is acceptable to open the dialog as in the second picture when the warnings are known in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a little unclear without some visuals. Can you provide some mocks of your efforts so far, for better context? The more effort, context and tradeoffs you provide can make the answer more useful to you, and the rest of the community.

Comment: How critical warning is? Does it relate to each selected entity of to some of them?

Comment: @MikeM, photos added.

Comment: @Serg the warning is important, but not critical. There is another option of a critical warning, in which there isn't an option to continue with warnings.The warning can be related to one/ multi selected entitites.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right the user has two different possibilities to start the operation.

If the user chooses to select items and then perform the operation the user was already warned about those items. 
If this is the case showing the first dialog is an unnecessary step. You should show the second screen with the warnings directly.

What you could consider, is an option to remove the items with warning directly in the dialog (maybe even remove all at once). Otherwise the user has to go back a step to do so. But said so, this depends on the overall workflow and the needs of the actual users.